# Replace substring several times with offset

Tags: c#, string

For example i have a string:

```
"abcd abcd abcd"
```

And i need to replace first 'b' for 'ed' and third 'c' for 'ad'(not exactly in that order).

I know indexes of these letters from the very beginning.

The problem is when i replacing first 'b' the index of third 'c' is shifting to right. So the only way to solve this task is to store indexes of letters which i want to replace and then increase or decrease their indexes depending on where i made a replacement and length of replacement string.

Is there any library which can do this for me?

**Update:**
The order of replacement is specified by user so i don't know which letter and when will be replaced.
The source string is very large and it's takes too long to calculate replacement indexes.

Comment: Why don't you consume string character by character? Output is built for each character and you won't need to adjust any index.

Comment: Can the replacement order jump back and forth in the string?  Ie. can you get first replace the 'b' at spot 1, then the 'd' at spot 8, then the 'a' at spot '5'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the indexes of the letters you wish to replace, then you can simply sort the list by their indexes descending, then work backwards through your string - that way, the letter indexes wont be altered.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple and static approach:

```
string s = "abcd abcd abcd";
string[] groups = s.Split(new[] {' '});
string firstGroup = groups[0].Replace("b", "ed");
string secondGroup = groups[1].Replace("c", "ad");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built in `Replace()` method for `string`.

```
var s = "abcd abcd abcd";
s = s.Replace("b", "ed");
s = s.Replace("c", "ad");
```

Much easier.

Comment: Same mistake I made but I deleted my answer. The OP doesn't want to replace all b's and c's.

Comment: I guess that was not something I could have deduced from the question. Sad that I got downvote for this.

Comment: It states clearly in the question: "And i need to replace first 'b' for 'ed' and third 'c' for 'ad'(not exactly in that order)."